# Dynamic numbers of column in 1 row

Tags: xslt, twitter-bootstrap

i have number of categories that i want to separate it into rows, the number of category in a row will base on `$catsInLine`. The `$catsInLine` are digit from 1 to 12. Each category will be wrap by DIVs with class from span1 to span 12. And the categories will be wrap again with `<div class="row-fluid">` for each row.

I tried below for hours and no luck getting the correct result.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <xsl:variable name="catsInLine">
        <xsl:value-of select="categories_in_line" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="column">
        <xsl:value-of select="(12 div $catsInLine)" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
        <xsl:if test="position() mod $catsInLine = 1 or position() = 1">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class="row-fluid"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <div class="span{$column}">
            <xsl:call-template name="category" />
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod $catsInLine = 0 or position() = last()">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;&#47;div&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

assume the `$catsInLine` is `2`,the result i wish to get is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <a>Category1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <a>Category2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <a>Category3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <a>Category4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

if the `$catsInLine` is `1`, the result should be

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <a>Category1</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <a>Category2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <a>Category3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <a>Category4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="categories/category[position() mod $catsInLine = 1 or
                                                 $catsInLine = 1]" 
                     mode="row" />

<!-- Separate template -->
<xsl:template match="category" mode="row">
  <div class="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates 
              select=". | following-sibling::category[position() &lt; $catsInLine]" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: the answer seem doesn't quite fit to my current code, i insert all the code that i was using and hope you can revise your answer for my

Comment: Could you include your whole XSLT if it's not too large?